# How to define prod/test launch scenarios for Android app?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app and I have different environments for testing and production releases (backend web server URL, debugging on/off, c2dm notifications e-mail account and a few others). I'd like to have those project configs to be stored in app structure in a convenient way (like xml file, not hardcoded in Java) and be able to switch between them with one switch (something like target="prod|test" in a place like AndroidManifest.xml. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to use the target with a specific framework (ant, maven)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a xml file to the res folder and parse it when running.

```
<data target="prod">
    <target id="prod">
        <debug>off</debug>
    </target>
    <target id="test">
       <debug>on</debug>
    </target>
</data>
```

So you will only have to change the target attribute. However you would also have your debug settings in the final app which could be a security risk.

Better way would probably be a xml file that you exchange depending whether you have prod or test.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Xeno, for your suggestion, actually I took a similar track, decided to keep the config settings in one XML file, and if there's any security concern about leaving it in the public release, I can remove unwanted entries as one of the release preparation steps (replacing XML files was exactly what didn't want to do).

Here are the details in case anyone needs a ready-to-implement solution in the future:

Usage — if using helper methods from `Config.java`, whenever you need a config setting value, you just write a line of code like `Config.getInstance().getXxx()`, e.g. `Config.getInstance().getApiServer()` to get the API server URL. Config XML file is parsed only once, on the first `Config.getInstance()` call.

1. I created `config.xml` file with `current-env` pointing to the currently active environment, `devel-env` and `prod-env` containing the actual config settings, and `default-env` containing common values for all environments (they can be overwritten in the particular environment sections:

   ```
   <current-env>prod-env</current-env>

   <devel-env>
       <label>devel</label>
       <api-server>http://monitor.test.xxx.com/</api-server>
       <notification-email>testnotifications.xxx@gmail.com</notification-email>
   </devel-env>

   <prod-env>
       <label></label>
       <api-server>http://monitor.xxx.com/</api-server>
       <notification-email>notifications.xxx@gmail.com</notification-email>
   </prod-env>

   <default-env>
       <http-connection-timeout-millis>5000</http-connection-timeout-millis>
       <http-so-timeout-millis>10000</http-so-timeout-millis>
       <api-root>api15/</api-root>
       <shared-data-key>com.xxx.monitor</shared-data-key>
   </default-env>
   ```
2. I wrote `Config.java` class that parses the `config.xml` and returns config values for the current environment:

   ```
   public class Config {
       public static final String TAG_CONFIG_ROOT = "config";
       public static final String TAG_CONFIG_PROD = "prod-env";
       public static final String TAG_CONFIG_DEVEL = "devel-env";
       public static final String TAG_CONFIG_DEFAULT = "default-env";
       public static final String TAG_CURRENT_ENV = "current-env";
       public static final String TAG_API_SERVER = "api-server";
       public static final String TAG_API_ROOT = "api-root";
       public static final String TAG_SHARED_DATA_KEY = "shared-data-key";
       public static final String TAG_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL = "notification-email";
       public static final String TAG_ENVIRONMENT_LABEL = "label";
       public static final String TAG_HTTP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = "http-connection-timeout-millis";
       public static final String TAG_HTTP_SO_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = "http-so-timeout-millis";

       private static Config instance = null;

       private XmlNode configRootNode = null;

       public static Config getInstance(Context context) {
           if (instance == null) {
               try {
                   instance = new Config(context);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   Log.err("Error creating Config instance", e);
               }
           }
           return instance;
       }

       private Config(Context context) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
           readConfig(context);
       }

       private void readConfig(Context context) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
           Resources res = context.getResources();
           XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.config);
           SimpleXmlDocumentModel xmlModel = new SimpleXmlDocumentModel();
           configRootNode = xmlModel.parseXml(xpp);
           return;
       }

       private String getCurrentEnv() {
           return configRootNode.getChildValue(TAG_CURRENT_ENV);
       }

       private String getConfigValue(String key) {
           String value;
           XmlNode envNode = configRootNode.getChild(getCurrentEnv());
           value = envNode.getChildValue(key);
           if (value == null) {
               value = getDefaultValue(key);
           }
           return value;
       }

       private String getDefaultValue(String key) {
           String value = null;
           XmlNode defaultNode = configRootNode.getChild(TAG_CONFIG_DEFAULT);
           if (defaultNode != null) {
               value = defaultNode.getChildValue(key);
           }
           return value;
       }

       public Integer getHttpConnectionTimeoutMillis() {
           return StringUtil.parseInteger(getConfigValue(Config.TAG_HTTP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS));
       }

       public Integer getHttpSoTimeoutMillis() {
           return StringUtil.parseInteger(getConfigValue(Config.TAG_HTTP_SO_TIMEOUT_MILLIS));
       }

       public String getApiServer() {
           return getConfigValue(Config.TAG_API_SERVER);
       }

       public String getApiRoot() {
           return getConfigValue(Config.TAG_API_ROOT);
       }

       public String getSharedDataKey() {
           return getConfigValue(Config.TAG_SHARED_DATA_KEY);
       }

       public String getNotificationEmail() {
           return getConfigValue(Config.TAG_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL);
       }

       public String getEnvironmentLabel() {
           return getConfigValue(Config.TAG_ENVIRONMENT_LABEL);
       }
   }
   ```

It uses 2 helper classes for xml parsing. Since they're pretty generic, I isolated them to a separate package so that they're reusable.

`SimpleXmlDocumentModel.java`:

```
    public class SimpleXmlDocumentModel {

        private XmlNode rootNode = null;

        public XmlNode parseXml(XmlResourceParser xpp) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            XmlNode currentNode = null;
            xpp.next();
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    String tagName = xpp.getName();
                    currentNode = addNode(currentNode, tagName);
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    currentNode = currentNode.parent;
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    currentNode.text = xpp.getText();
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
            return rootNode;
        }

        private XmlNode addNode(XmlNode currentNode, String name) {
            XmlNode newNode = new XmlNode();
            newNode.parent = currentNode;
            if (currentNode != null) {
                if (currentNode.nodes == null) {
                    currentNode.nodes = new HashMap<String, XmlNode>();
                }
                currentNode.nodes.put(name, newNode);
            } else {
                rootNode = newNode;
            }
            currentNode = newNode;
            return currentNode;
        }


    }
```

`XmlNode.java`:

```
    public class XmlNode {

        String text = null;
        Map<String, XmlNode> nodes = null;
        XmlNode parent = null;

        public XmlNode getChild(String key) {
            return (nodes != null) ? nodes.get(key) : null;
        }

        public String getChildValue(String key) {
            String value = null;
            if (nodes != null) {
                XmlNode valueNode = nodes.get(key);
                if (valueNode != null) {
                    value= valueNode.text;
                }
            }
            return value;
        }

    }
```

The simple XML document model above doesn't support more complex entities or entity lists, but serves my purposes and is stupid simple.